# Why isn't the pattern in this code exhaustive?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
splitWith :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitWith f [] = []
splitWith f list = pre : (splitWith f suf)
    where (pre, suf) = break f list
```

This function should split a list according to a predicate. But I get an infinite recursion.

Comment: Because `break` does *not guarantees* progress?

Comment: The patterns are exhaustive, otherwise you would get a runtime exception (or compile time warning). The issue here is infinite recursion rather than exhaustiveness.

Comment: The word you are looking for is 'generative'. Also, consider the very trivial case of `splitWith (const False)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`break` is defined as:

> **`break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`**
>
> `break`, applied to a predicate `p` and a list `xs`, returns a tuple
>   where first element is **longest prefix (possibly empty)** of `xs` of
>   elements that do not satisfy `p` and second element is the remainder
>   of the list:
>
> ```
> break (> 3) [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4] == ([1,2,3],[4,1,2,3,4])
> break (< 9) [1,2,3] == ([],[1,2,3])
> break (> 9) [1,2,3] == ([1,2,3],[])
> ```

So once you have done the first `break`, all the remaining `break`s will simply split the list into an empty list and the original list. As a result, there is no progress in the pattern so to speak. Unless all the elements do not satisfy the predicate, you will keep iterating over a list where the first element satisifies the predicate, and never get rid of it.

What you probably want is to interleave the `break` with the `span`:

```
splitWith :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitWith f [] = []
splitWith f list = pre1 : pre2 : (splitWith f suf2)
    where (pre1, suf1) = break f list
          (pre2, suf2) = span f suf1
```

This will split the given list interleaved in a list of elements where the predicate is *not* satisfied, and a list where it is satisfied.

In case you do not want the latter, you can simply `dropWhile` these:

```
splitWith :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitWith f [] = []
splitWith f list = pre : (splitWith f $ dropWhile f suf)
    where (pre1, suf) = break f list
```

Comment: I think `(pre2, suf2) = span f list` should be `(pre2, suf2) = span f suf1`?

Comment: Thanks to both @Al

Answer (score 2):

It'd be because this will continually add an empty list to the end.

You can see this is if you take some arbitrary quantity of values from the infinite collection:

```
*Main> take 10 $ splitWith (==5) [1,2,3,4,5]
[[1,2,3,4],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
```

If you `break (==5) [5]`, the result is `([],[5])` which gets pattern matched into `pre` as `[]` and `suf` as `[5]`. The next iteration gets the same `break (==5) [5]` to evaluate... and so it goes.

**update:**

I'm not sure of the exact semantics you're after, but this might be helpful in formulating the function you want:

```
splitWith :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitWith f [] = []
splitWith f xs = doSplitWith [] xs
  where
    doSplitWith first second @ (y:ys) =
      if f y
      then (reverse first) : [second]
      else doSplitWith (y:first) ys


splitWith' f xs = takeWhile (not . f) xs : [dropWhile (not . f) xs]
```

Tho I guess that'd be more like `splitAt` or something, wouldn't it?